# Doesn't time out when using TimeConstrained with FindFit for some data

Tags: evaluation, crash

To summarize: My problem is that I have some code that won't terminate even when I use TimeConstrained to force it to terminate after 1 second. My question is whether there is an alternative solution to forcing the evaluation to terminate. I am running Mathematica 11.2 on Windows 10 with an Intel i9 processor overclocked at 4.5Gz and with 64MB RAM.

Specifics: I am using the following code to fit a model to time series data:

```
system = {
CC'[t] == b M[t] - CC[t] d,
M'[t] == -M[t] a t^B,
CC[0] == data[[1, 2]], M[0] == data[[1, 2]]};

model = ParametricNDSolveValue[system,  CC, {t, First[data][[1]], Last[data] 
[[1]]}, {a, B, b, d}]

fit = FindFit[data, model[a, B, b, d][t], {{a, 0}, {B, 3}, {b, .5}, {d, 
.01}}, t]
```

This works fine for most of the data I have tested. However, for some data, FindFit never terminates and I have to abort kernel in order to halt the evaluation.

Here are three examples of data that cause the problem:

```
data = {{0, 4496.5}, {24, 37416.5}, {48, 74462.7}, {72, 57204.8}};
data = {{0, 4500}, {24, 37000}, {48, 74000}, {55, 74000}, {72, 
57000}};
data = {{0, 4500}, {12, 25000}, {16, 29000}, {20, 33000}, {24, 
37000}, {30, 50000}, {35, 65000}, {40, 70000}, {48, 74000}, {55, 
74000}, {60, 73000}, {65, 70000}, {68, 65000}, {72, 57000}};
```

and here are two examples of data that don't cause a problem:

```
data = {{0, 5117}, {24, 66183.3}, {48, 119679}, {72, 79002.2}};
data = {{0, 4500}, {24, 37000}, {48, 74000}, {55, 70000}, {72, 
57000}};
```

(By the way, I am aware that the model with some of these data is being overfit. These are just examples).

The REAL problem is that the problem persists even when using TimeConstrained. I tried adding TimeConstrained to FindFit as follows:

```
fit = TimeConstrained[FindFit[data, model[a, B, b, d][t], {{a, 0}, {B, 3}, 
{b, .5}, {d, .01}}, t, MaxIterations -> 10], 1]
```

But this doesn't help: the computation never terminates and the only way to abort the evaluation is to quit the kernal (note that the problem occurs even when MaxIterations is set to only 10).

Since I want to run this code in a loop on a large number of data sets, I would like a way to force Mathematica to time out if the evaluation won't terminate.

Any help is much appreciated in advance!

Comment: I cannot get the code above to run.

Comment: Sorry Daniel. I had an extra square bracket in my pasted code. I just edited the question and the code should run now.

Comment: I might be missing something but why would you try to estimate 5 parameters (`a`, `b`, `B`, `d`, and the error variance) with just 4 (or even 5) data points?  I understand you acknowledge that these are just small examples but larger amounts of data would likely not have the same issues.

Comment: The datasets that "work" aren't converging even with `MaxIterations -> 1000`.  If  you get warnings or errors, it is essential that you mention that.

Comment: Hi JimB, I just added a dataset with 14 points that also has the problem. So, while I agree that this won't be as big an issue with larger data sets, the problem does arise even when data sets are larger.

Comment: When I run the line `model = ...` I get several error messages. I suggest you quit your session  or at least `Clear[model,system] and start over with the definitions. Then post the code that works for you.

Answer (score 3):

I think your model is overparameterized (and not because of the amount of data).  If one sets `a` to some value, then `FindFit` (and better yet `NonlinearModelFit`) finds a solution.  If one tries lots of different values for `a` and plots those values against the associated estimates of `B`, then one gets a near-perfect correlation.  Because of the near-perfect correlation, there is no unique solution and a single iteration in `FindFit` just continues to wander around in hyperspace.  (I know that's not a great or even accurate explanation.)

So I suggest either (1) Removing `a` (i.e., setting it to 1) or (2) rethinking your model.  Here are the results with setting `a` to 1.  (I've also divide `t` by 100 to reduce round-off error.)

```
data = {{0, 4500}, {12, 25000}, {16, 29000}, {20, 33000}, {24, 37000}, 
  {30, 50000}, {35, 65000}, {40, 70000}, {48, 74000}, {55, 74000},
  {60, 73000}, {65, 70000}, {68, 65000}, {72, 57000}};

system = {CC'[t] == b M[t] - CC[t] d,
   M'[t] == -M[t] (t/100)^B,
   CC[0] == data[[1, 2]],
   M[0] == data[[1, 2]]};

model = ParametricNDSolveValue[system, 
   CC, {t, First[data][[1]], Last[data][[1]]}, {b, B, d}];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
   model[b, B, d][t], {{b, 1.4}, {B, 3}, {d, .1}}, t];

nlm["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1. & 0.918946 & 0.97062 \\
 0.918946 & 1. & 0.983729 \\
 0.97062 & 0.983729 & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

```
nlm["BestFitParameters"] 
(* {b -> 0.43894, B -> 4.08547, d -> 0.0111581} *)

Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[z], {z, 0, 72}]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

**Update**

I think the main issue is still that the model is overparameterized (and that is not to be confused with overfitting).  If one re-parameterizes the model such that the coefficients to be estimated are on approximately the same scale, then the fitting algorithms are much more stable.  The catch, of course, is having both a good idea as to how to re-parameterize and good starting values.  Here is an approach that will fit all 4 parameters: `a`, `b`, `B`, and `d`.

```
data = {{0, 4500}, {12, 25000}, {16, 29000}, {20, 33000}, {24, 37000}, {30, 50000},
   {35, 65000}, {40, 70000}, {48, 74000}, {55, 74000}, {60, 73000}, {65, 70000},
   {68, 65000}, {72, 57000}};

system = {CC'[t] == b M[t] - CC[t] d/100,
   M'[t] == -M[t] Exp[loga] (t/100)^B,
   CC[0] == data[[1, 2]],
   M[0] == data[[1, 2]]};

model = ParametricNDSolveValue[system, 
   CC, {t, First[data][[1]], Last[data][[1]]}, {loga, b, B, d}];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
   model[loga, b, B, d][t], {{loga, 14}, {b, 0.4}, {B, 22}, {d, 1}}, t];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {loga -> 13.9864, b -> 0.413836, B -> 21.9799, d -> 0.924626} *)

Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 72}]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

But note that `loga` and `B` are still highly correlated (0.99942) which suggests that the model is either overparameterized or not "well parameterized".

```
nlm["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1. & -0.066721 & 0.99942 & 0.159348 \\
 -0.066721 & 1. & -0.0439451 & 0.884898 \\
 0.99942 & -0.0439451 & 1. & 0.189313 \\
 0.159348 & 0.884898 & 0.189313 & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$